# What's alternate for Pthreads::kill() about Thread class of pthreads version 3

Tags: php, multithreading, process, pthreads, kill

The `kill()` method has been removed from PECL pthreads library version 3.

See manual from archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210410123359/https://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.kill.php

> Warning: This method has been removed in pthreads v3. 
> Warning: The programmer should not ordinarily kill Threads by force.

So as you can see removed in new version:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Now what's alternate for kill or terminate the proccess from out of class that started with the Thread class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no alternative. This method was removed exactly because it's not safe to kill a thread like this using pthreads. Check [this](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/708) and [this](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/588) issue in the pthreads repository for more details and possible workarounds.

Since pthreads was discontinued, I recommend switching to the new [parallel](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.parallel.php) extension. It has a [kill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/parallel-runtime.kill.php) method.